# Remmina refuses to scale the remote screen res to fit in smaller client screen

Tags: display-resolution, remmina, scaling

[image: image shows remote PC screen as cropped]

Remote PC screen is cropped

Running remmina client 1.2.0-rcgit-29 (git rcgit-29)

Connected to remote Ubuntu desktop using VNC.

Remote desktop resolution is too high for client screen. There are no available or working option to scale the remote screen image to fit in the Remmina client window.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried changing the settings in VNC? see[What control do I have over monitors and resolution](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/faq/monitors.html)

Comment: The comments in that link are simply untrue for my situation - "By default, the desktop is automatically scaled."
This simply isn't happening. And there does not appear to be any way to force Remmina to scale the image. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on both remote and client machine BTW, so the Windows version of Remmina may be different.

Comment: Remmina dev here. Upgrade to a newer version please and let me know. We worked a lot on the scaling.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue (same release). Upgrading to 1.3.4 did not work for me, same issue appeared.

The solution was to put scaling back to 100%. I am not sure this can be considered a solution, as 100% scaling for 4K makes everything tiny. But at least you can access your entire desktop.

Answer (score -1):

With remote Debian 10 (xRDP) and Ubuntu 20.04 as client (Remmina), i had first the same problem by connecting directly in RDP mode.
Finally i save the configuration precising the Resolution: "Use client Resolution" option and network connection type "LAN".
It works well now.
Hope it can help.